# i am trying to execute the before insert trigger , but i m getting the sql errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

what i want to achieve is i have a table called orders.
i want to perform the before insert trigger on my orders table.i want to capture the
  username of person performing INSERT into table.
one table called info which contain the user.

this is my code

```
create table orders
(
  order_id int,
  quantity  int,
  cost int,
  total_cost int,
  created_date datetime,
  created_by varchar(20)
)

create  trigger beforeInsertdata
 before insert
  on orders
 for each row
  declare 
 v_username varchar2(10);
begin
 -- Find username of person performing INSERT into table

    SELECT user INTO v_username
    FROM info;
 -- Update create_date field to current system date
    :new.create_date := sysdate;
 -- Update created_by field to the username of the person performing the INSERT
    :new.created_by := v_username;

END;

--user information--
create table info
(
  userid int ,
  user_name varchar(10)
)

insert into info values(1,'vivek')
select * from info
```

Comment: You cannot *perform* or *execute* a trigger - SQL Server will do that automatically, when appropriate

Comment: This is not valid SQL Server / T-SQL syntax: `for each row` as well as: `:new.create_date := sysdate;`

Comment: now only i got the answer for this that sql server is not supporting the before insert trigger it only support the after and instead of trigger.i think only that oracle support this before insert trigger.sory for this----

Comment: Take a look @ T-SQL syntax.  SQL Server is not Oracle!

Comment: SQL Server supports `FOR INSERT` (which is AFTER insert) or `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers. But T-SQL syntax is definitely different from Oracle's PL/SQL syntax - you'll need to change your trigger code no matter what....

Comment: Even if the question was tagged with Oracle, it is totally unclear to me what the question is.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, triggers are classified into two main types:-

1)After Triggers (For Triggers)

2)Instead Of Triggers

and the syntax for trigger is

```
  CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON table_name 
  [FOR|AFTER|INSTEAD OF] [INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE]

  AS

  //your code goes here   

  GO
```

NOTE :  FOR keyword used for INSERT |UPDATE Command where as AFTER USED FOR DELETE Command.

Comment: thanks for answer now only i got the answer for this that sql server is not supporting the before insert trigger it only support the after and instead of trigger.i think only that oracle support this before insert trigger.sory for this----

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're really trying to do. I've modified your code sample so that it will work on SQL2K5 and made some assumptions about how you're wanting to use the connected user account.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id int,
  quantity int,
  cost int,
  total_cost int,
  created_date datetime,
  created_by varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE info (
  userid int,
  user_name varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO info
VALUES (1, 'vivek');

SELECT *
FROM info;

CREATE TRIGGER orders_InsteadOfInsert ON orders
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- varchar(10) is to match your table, but probably should be larger
  DECLARE @CurrentUser VarChar(10);
  SELECT @CurrentUser = SYSTEM_USER;

  IF (@CurrentUser NOT IN (SELECT user_name FROM info)) BEGIN
    -- consider using an identity column for the key instead of this
    INSERT INTO info (userid, user_name)
    SELECT
      ISNULL((SELECT MAX(userid) FROM info), 0) + 1,
      @CurrentUser;
  END;

  INSERT INTO orders (order_id, quantity, cost, total_cost, created_date, created_by)
  SELECT
    INS.order_id,
    INS.quantity,
    INS.cost,
    INS.total_cost,
    GETDATE(),
    @CurrentUser
  FROM INSERTED INS;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but now only i got the answer for this that sql server is not supporting the before insert trigger it only support the after and instead of trigger.i think only that oracle support this before insert trigger.sory for this----

Comment: Right, SQL Server doesn't support BEFORE triggers. You can get INSTEAD OF to work in a similar manner, though. The INSTEAD OF trigger replaces the INSERT operation. Meaning that if you don't perform the INSERT within the trigger it never happens. In that way you could abort INSERT if, for instance, the connected user isn't already in your info table. Hope that helps...I think this is a matter of semantics given how you're trying to use it.